# Taken picture doesn't is disappeared after camera event

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Im implementing a camera to my app at the moment. The camera is working. It opens and I can also take pictures. But the problem appears when I press "use picture" then the image should appear on a card, but there is just an empty card without the picture. Do you have any ideas? I upload the code below.

HTML

```
<ion-content padding> 
 <ion-card>
  <img [src]="photo">
 </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

TypeScript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

/**
 * Generated class for the PostPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-post',
  templateUrl: 'post.html',
})
export class PostPage {
  public photos: any;
  public base64Image: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private camera: Camera) {

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.photos = [];
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){                    //Damit Kamera automatisch öffent
   const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}


this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64:
 this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  this.photos.push(this.base64Image);
  this.photos.reverse();

}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
  }
}
```

Comment: `<img [src]="photo">` is not using the photos array...

Comment: so what do I have to write then?

Comment: you want to show multiple pictures?

Comment: `<ion-card *ngFor="let photo of photos">
  <img [src]="photo">
 </ion-card>` is this what you are looking for?
</ion-content>

Comment: Ok thx it works now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `photos` array in the ts file in which you are pushing the image object. You just need to loop through it using `*ngFor`.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let photo of photos"> 
    <img [src]="photo"> 
</ion-card>
```